# What replaced sndrec32 from Windows XP in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, system-sounds

I have a small VB Script that calls a system sound as an alert. In Windows XP I used [sndrec32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_Recorder_%28Windows%29) to play that sound. But sndrec32 was not continued in Vista and Windows 7. It was light and quick and ideal for such tasks.

**Q:** What replaced this tool? When you click the test button in the sounds window what is it that plays it?

Answer (score 10):

> In Vista, Sound Recorder is instead called SoundRecorder.exe and has different command-line switches.

[image]
[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_Recorder_%28Windows%29)

---

- The only command line option I found so far can only be used for recording.
  `SoundRecorder /FILE myrec.wma /DURATION 0000:00:30`
- The old `/PLAY "C:\Path\File.wav" /CLOSE` switch doesn't work anymore
- You can use `wmplayer.exe %windir%\media\ding.wav` instead.
  It supports several [command line parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386383.aspx) and can be started minimized
- You could copy the old sndrec32.exe [from Windows XP over to your Windows 7](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/windows-xps-sound-recorder-sndrec32exe-in-64-bit/ad0a6f3b-f3df-48cc-998a-59e0553241be) into the same place. It needs the "Run as Administrator" option checked

Comment: sndrec32.exe is also in Windows Server 2003 if you have that handy like I did.

Comment: I couldn't get it to start minimized by running from a command line. Found an answer here to create an run a VBA script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313709/play-invisible-music-with-batch-file

Comment: Blech, so ugly. Why do they have to change the things they got right?